# How to best explain to users how their details will be used?

Tags: usability, gui-design, user-behavior, user-research, information-architecture

What would be the best approach to explain to users that their information will be used to:

**1- help authenticate them if they do get locked out of their account.**

**2- Communicate with them regarding products and services.**

The main difficulty i am facing is that we are attempting to capture:

- 2 emails ; both Primary and Recovery
- Mobile and landline numbers

In addition we also need to be able to **verify those details**.

I would like your opinion on:

**How best can this be achieved via language and UI so as to provide a seamless experience?**

**What are UX best practices when capturing and verifying user details particularly when it comes to UI?**

Comment: Basically, don't do it all in one form. Walk them through a series of steps and provide a concise explanation of why you need info X, Y, and Z. If you need to verify stuff then do it in the step where it's relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look at how for example facebook handles this:

first they show you what the website can and might access

and under that it shows you what it cant do.

this order is important so the user understands what he accepts when giving you his information and what he doesnt need to worry about when accepting the form.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXj43.png

sorry this is in german but im sure you know this form